# MIME type audio/mpeg is not streaming?

Tags: ios4, audio, streaming, audio-streaming, shoutcast

I am using [Matt Gallagher's](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/streaming-and-playing-live-mp3-stream.html) streaming here.

I am trying to play SHOUTCast API returned urls. But Media with MIME type audio/mpeg are not being played without showing any error.

But MIME type audio/aacp are playing fine.

Why so? Do I need to use something other than this?

IN Matt's tutorial he stated that for mp3 files I need to add `fileTypeHint` but that is already there and for `MediaType = audio/mpeg` it is not going inside any of case in below function.

What need to change?

```
+ (AudioFileTypeID)hintForFileExtension:(NSString *)fileExtension
{
    AudioFileTypeID fileTypeHint = kAudioFileAAC_ADTSType;
    if ([fileExtension isEqual:@"mp3"])
    {
        fileTypeHint = kAudioFileMP3Type;
    }
    else if ([fileExtension isEqual:@"wav"])
    {
        fileTypeHint = kAudioFileWAVEType;
    }
    else if ([fileExtension isEqual:@"aifc"])
    {
        fileTypeHint = kAudioFileAIFCType;
    }
    else if ([fileExtension isEqual:@"aiff"])
    {
        fileTypeHint = kAudioFileAIFFType;
    }
    else if ([fileExtension isEqual:@"m4a"])
    {
        fileTypeHint = kAudioFileM4AType;
    }
    else if ([fileExtension isEqual:@"mp4"])
    {
        fileTypeHint = kAudioFileMPEG4Type;
    }
    else if ([fileExtension isEqual:@"caf"])
    {
        fileTypeHint = kAudioFileCAFType;
    }
    else if ([fileExtension isEqual:@"aac"])
    {
        fileTypeHint = kAudioFileAAC_ADTSType;
    }
    return fileTypeHint;
}
```

And With this streamer how do I work in condition where I am playing top5 stations and for that I have fetch all URL from PLS file and save them in an Array.

Now how do I continuously play them as it is radio

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same problem. It seems that if no `fileExtension` is there the default `fileTypeHint` is `kAudioFileAAC_ADTSType` (as the first line of the function).

Changing it to `AudioFileTypeID fileTypeHint = kAudioFileMP2Type` will solve the `MediaType = audio/mpeg` problem.